# How do I stop Eclipse (STS) from creating a new runtime configuration every time I start a server

Tags: java, eclipse, server, spring-tool-suite

I'm using Spring Tool Suite (rejiggered eclipse) and for some reason, occasionally when I start a server (servers view pane, right click, start), instead of using the runtime configuration I've edited (specifically, with new VM args, e.g. -Xmx1234g, -Dlog4j.doAThing=true etc), it will generate a new runtime configuration (so instead of Server-Name, it will run Server-Name(1), or if that already exists Server-Name(2)) with defaults and run that instead. It's more irritating than anything, but I'd like to find out what the cause might be and fix it instead of just tolerating it running wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than right clicking on the server and selecting Run, try clicking Run -> Run Configurations... from the menu bar at the top of the screen and then find and run the server from there.  Alternatively there is a green run button on the tool bars with a small down arrow next to it.  There should probably be a launch option for the server shown there.

Comment: This is what I've been doing as a workaround. I'm able to work around the problem, I'm trying to solve the root cause

Answer (score 0):

I have the default config called 
The following worked for me:
Created config called X copied VM args from , copied User Entries JARs on the Classpath tab. Launched the config to verify it is working
Removed config . Only have X left
Now launching server from the Servers view launches my config X

Perhaps Classpath tab User Entries are not matchi